# Localhost deployment - asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, localhost

I am trying to deploy my app to localhost and can't get it done. Until now, I did the following:

Properties -> Web -> Use Local IIS / Create Virtual Directory

When I run my app it says

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Config Source:

```
Config Source:
34:   <system.webServer>
35:     <modules>
36:       <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
```

Config Error:

```
Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

If I remove modules and start Debugging I get the following:

```
The Web server could not find the requested resource.
```

If I manually go to localhost/AppName I get this:

```
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

and localhost/AppName/Home

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

and the path D:\Projects\AppName\AppName\home (not corresponding with the physical one, it should have been D:\Projects\AppName\AppName\Controllers\Home )

What should I do?

Edit: I also gave full permissions to my user. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the framework version in application pool is set as 4.0.30319 (4.5)
Also ensure that the folder structure is proper

Add a global error handler and log the received exception to see what's happening.

This link has samples on error handling.
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/handling-errors-effectively-in-asp.net-mvc/